# Remove everything between "/*" and "*/" in JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would one remove all text between /* and */ (including these characters) in a string in JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: I would select it in Notepad and hit the Backspace key...

Comment: with `replace` and `RegExp`. no problem

Comment: @CodeBird Don't you mean two problems?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666, no I am answering the thanks too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Your regex would be

```
/\/\*.*?\*\//g
```

#### 2. The JS code to do the replacement would be:

```
your_str = your_str.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g, '');
```

#### 3. Here is your explanation for the regex:

```
Match the character "/" literally
Match the character "*" literally
Match any single character that is not a line break character
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
Match the character "*" literally
Match the character "/" literally
```

Comment: Note, this isn't a fool-proof solution for removing comments (i.e. `var string = "this is not /* a comment */"` would still be affected).  However, that is way beyond the scope of the question -- good answer.

Comment: Works great thank you so much! The scope was indeed not for a full parser or parsing JavaScript and its fringes, just a way to have comment functionality for a small text-based interaction definition syntax.